# Indicator variables - No aces in a bridge match

Tags: probability, statistics

I'm trying to learn how to solve questions using indicator variables but am having trouble. How does one solve the question below using them?

> What is the expected value of the number of players with no aces in their hands in a bridge match?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write $I_A$ for the indicator function of the event $A$. Let $N$, $S$, $W$, $E$ be the events that North etc. get no aces.

Then $I_N+I_S+I_W+I_E$ is the number of ace-less players. Then
$$E(I_N+I_S+I_W+I_E)=E(I_N)+\cdots=P(N)+\cdots.$$

Comment: Just to be sure the answer would be $ 4*(48 C 13) / (52 C 13)$ right?

Comment: It is indeed four times the probability that a given play gets no aces.